# Virtualbox crashes on VM boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, surface-2

Less than a second after the Windows booting UI appears in a newly created VM with a Windows CD attached VirtualBox crashes.

I installed VirtualBox with apt (Version: 6.0.14-dfsg-1), ran `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` after being prompted to, created a 64bit Win10 VM, booted it, and loaded an .iso downloaded from Microsoft (Win10_1909_English_x64.iso).

I saw the booting screen, I saw a flash of the Windows installation screen, and then the window with the VM closed. The main VirtualBox window (that I started the VM from) remained open.

No portion of VBox.log appeared pertinent, so I uploaded it to [a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ZhujEHuQ).

I'm running kubuntu with a [custom kernel](https://github.com/qzed/linux-surface-kernel) to add support for Surface laptops with the window manager i3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned too much memory to the VM, even though I was still within the zone shown as green. Using the default worked.